# PPA repository for dell

Tags: apt, dell, ppa, add-apt-repository

`sudo apt-get update` failed

```
> W: Failed to fetch
> http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/dists/trusty-dell-biz-vivid-skl/Release.gpg
> Unable to connect to dell.archive.canonical.com:http:
> 
> W: Failed to fetch
> http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/dists/trusty-dell-dino2/Release.gpg
> Unable to connect to dell.archive.canonical.com:http:
> 
> W: Failed to fetch
> http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/dists/trusty-dell/Release.gpg
> Unable to connect to dell.archive.canonical.com:http:
> 
> W: Failed to fetch
> http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/dists/trusty-dell-biz-vivid-skl/public/binary-amd64/Packages
> Unable to connect to dell.archive.canonical.com:http:
> 
> W: Failed to fetch
> http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/dists/trusty-dell-biz-vivid-skl/public/binary-i386/Packages
> Unable to connect to dell.archive.canonical.com:http:
> 
> W: Failed to fetch
> http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/dists/trusty-dell-biz-vivid-skl/public/i18n/Translation-en_US
> Unable to connect to dell.archive.canonical.com:http:
> 
> W: Failed to fetch
> http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/dists/trusty-dell-biz-vivid-skl/public/i18n/Translation-en
> Unable to connect to dell.archive.canonical.com:http:
> 
> W: Failed to fetch
> http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/dists/trusty-dell-dino2/public/binary-amd64/Packages
> Unable to connect to dell.archive.canonical.com:http:
> 
> W: Failed to fetch
> http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/dists/trusty-dell-dino2/public/binary-i386/Packages
> Unable to connect to dell.archive.canonical.com:http:
> 
> W: Failed to fetch
> http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/dists/trusty-dell-dino2/public/i18n/Translation-en_US
> Unable to connect to dell.archive.canonical.com:http:
> 
> W: Failed to fetch
> http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/dists/trusty-dell-dino2/public/i18n/Translation-en
> Unable to connect to dell.archive.canonical.com:http:
> 
> W: Failed to fetch
> http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/dists/trusty-dell/public/binary-amd64/Packages
> Unable to connect to dell.archive.canonical.com:http:
> 
> W: Failed to fetch
> http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/dists/trusty-dell/public/binary-i386/Packages
> Unable to connect to dell.archive.canonical.com:http:
> 
> W: Failed to fetch
> http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/dists/trusty-dell/public/i18n/Translation-en_US
> Unable to connect to dell.archive.canonical.com:http:
> 
> W: Failed to fetch
> http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/dists/trusty-dell/public/i18n/Translation-en
> Unable to connect to dell.archive.canonical.com:http:
> 
> W: Failed to fetch
> http://oem.archive.canonical.com/updates/dists/trusty-oem-sp1/Release.gpg
> Unable to connect to oem.archive.canonical.com:http:
> 
> W: Failed to fetch
> http://oem.archive.canonical.com/updates/dists/trusty-oem/Release.gpg 
> Unable to connect to oem.archive.canonical.com:http:
> 
> W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old
> ones used instead.
```

Seems like I need add ppa repository.

Could you please help?

Comment: try this `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:dell-team/ppa` then `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: @George, I have tried this.

Comment: All of the "hosts" you can't connect to have invalid hostnames: `dell.archive.canonical.com:http:`. Do you have a misplaced "http:" in your configuration?